# Cleaning Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, disk-usage, cleanup

I'm new with Ubuntu so I don't understand most of it.
A few days ago, everytime that I start the computer, I have a prompt box saying that my disk is full and I have the option to check the disk with the Disk Analyzer.

But since I don't have any idea of what to delete I don't want to touch anything. 
I started checking my user folder and delete everything that wasn't useful there but I don't have much.
What else should I do?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check what's lurking in your Downloads folder. That's typically the #1 offender when it comes to low disk space.

Clear your browser cache manually e.g. ~/.mozilla/firefox/Cache or ~/cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache. This can free up 1GB sometimes.

You can also run from a command line *sudo apt-get purge* to remove old configuration files then go into Software Center or Synaptic and select apps you know you don't use.

The Disk Usage Analyzer is available under Ubuntu > Accessories > Disk Usage Analyzer. It shows which files and folders take up the most space.

Removing the old kernel is explained at [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) and can make space.

Comment: Before I saw your answer I found other posts with similar issues and I did 
Apt-get autoclean
and other similar commands.
Then I installed Bleachbit and right now it's cleaning stuff
Also, removed some apps that I installed and didn't use.
Just moved a big folder from the Downloads folder to an external HDD.
Just when I wanted to open a video, the prompt box appeared again.
It says something like that the file root folder it's only 200mb left.
I'll clean the browser manually (altough I think that Bleachbit did that already) and see to remove the old kernel.

Thanks.

Comment: Bleachbit is groovy, and it sure can make browsers squeakyclean, but some folks in Linux land are very underthrilled with it since you can delete too much. They have not gotten specific as to what Too Much is, but I will poke the sleeping penguins and ask when time permits. Just thought a headsup could be helpful.  And, check the checkmark if my answer did the job, for we get brownie points for useful help we can use to encourage folks to help us with Big Problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Ubuntu Tweak. It has a Janitor to help cleaning cache, old configs and unnecessary package.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```